# Skip a feature file if contains failure in Cucumber JS

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

So if I have 4 tests in total, if the first test fails, I want to fail-fast on that first test then I want to continue running the other 3 tests/feature files.

What it is doing now, which I don't like, is it will fail as soon as one test fails and it will NOT run any of the other feature files.

Any idea ?

I tried in cucumber options:

```
'fail-fast': true
```

but will stop the execution if a failure occurs

Comment: I have few questions here to get more clearer on your post: 1) What are the details displaying related to other 3 tests/ feature files in the console once the first test fails? 2) Are you guys using @After with driver.quit() ?.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to skip the remaining tests within a feature file once a test has failed within it, you will need to do the following:

1. At the top of each feature file, add a tag like `@feature_<something unique>`.
2. Add a `Before` and `After` hook to track the tags and determine if a feature has failed:

```js
// a place to track all of the failed scenarios.
const failedFeatures = [];

// identifies the feature tag using the pickle object.
function getFeature(pickle) {
    return pickle.tags.map(i => i.name).filter(i => i.indexOf('@feature_') === 0)[0];
}

// determines if the feature has failed, if it has then skip this test.
Before(function ({ pickle }) {
    const feature = getFeature(pickle);
    if (failedFeatures.indexOf(feature) >= 0) {
        return 'skipped';
    }
});

// if a test has failed, record that this feature has also failed.
After(function ({ pickle, result }) {
    const feature = getFeature(pickle);
    if (result.status === 'failed') {
        failedFeatures.push(feature);
    }
});
```

Live Demonstration: https://testjam.io/?p=CW0qadImXwzRUTLLgvJY